# Path finding issue caused due to return statement in recursion

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following wall problem (on matrix) with 3 type of queries:

> 1 x y

- build the wall between cells (x, y) and (x, y+1). If there is already exist a wall between them, this query is ignored.

> 2 x y

- build the wall between cells (x, y) and (x+1, y). If there is already exist a wall between them, this query is ignored.

> 3 x1 y1 x2 y2

- check if cells (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are connected. You must answer 1 if they are connected, 0 otherwise.

You can move only right or bottom if there is **no wall**.

I have coded it like this:

```
#Declarations and Assignments

#q = number of above listed queries to execute

rows,cols,q = (int(x) for x in input().split())
mat = [[None]*cols for _ in range(rows)]

class cell:
    def __init__(Self):
        Self.wr = False #Wall to right
        Self.wb = False #Wall at bottom

#safety conition i.e. checking walls

def isSafe(mat,oper,r,c):
    if(r>=rows or c>=cols):
        return False
    elif(oper == 0 and mat[r][c].wr == True):
        return False
    elif(oper == 1 and mat[r][c].wb == True):
        return False
    else:
        return True

#Recursivepath finder

def path(mat,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    #print('path from', x1,y1)
    if(x1 == x2 and y1 == y2):
        return True
    elif(x1 > x2 and y1 > y2):
        return False
    else:
        if(isSafe(mat,0,x1,y1)):
            path(mat,x1,y1+1,x2,y2)
        if(isSafe(mat,1,x1,y1)):
            path(mat,x1+1,y1,x2,y2)
        return

#For prining the matrix

def printMat(mat):
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,cols):
            print('For',i,j,':',mat[i][j].wr , ' ', mat[i][j].wb,end="\t")
        print('\n')

#Forming Matrix

for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        mat[i][j] = cell()

#Taking the q queries

for i in range(0,q):
    t = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    if(t[0] == 1):
        mat[t[1]][t[2]].wr = True
    elif(t[0] == 2):
        mat[t[1]][t[2]].wb = True
    elif(t[0] == 3):
        #print('Path from', t[1],t[2],'to',t[3],t[4])
        if(path(mat,t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4])):
            print(1)
        else: print(0)
```

let the sample input be:

4 5 7
 #(A 4x5 matrix and 7 queries)

2 1 0

1 1 1

1 2 1

2 2 0

2 2 1

1 0 1

3 0 0 2 1

On execution, I can see that I have already reached 2,1 from 0,0. Also, the function finds all the paths possible to 2,1 but the final result always prints as 0 instead of 1. That means the path() (Despite of reaching the target node and finding all possible paths) does not return true. This is probably returning in a recursion issue. Can someone please solve this problem and explain **return statement in recursion**?

Comment: `if(isSafe(mat,0,x1,y1)):
            path(mat,x1,y1+1,x2,y2)
        if(isSafe(mat,1,x1,y1)):
            path(mat,x1+1,y1,x2,y2)
        return` you're not using return value of `path` and you're returning `None` instead of `True` or `False`. Intentional?

Comment: Yes. Just to transfer the control of program. Decision making happens in the above two statements.